# preg_split for both a space and a forward slash

Tags: php, string, split, explode, preg-split

I am trying to basically explode a string with both a space and a forward slash. This is what I have:

```
$array = preg_split("/[\s,\/]+/", $string)
```

But I think I am doing something wrong. I have searched online but I can't really grasp how you enclose or define the characters. Is space \s? I thought slash forward was / but I am not sure anymore.

Thank you,

Comment: Works fine [here](http://codepad.org/vRwrudcd) ?

Comment: Your pattern will split on 1 or more `space` `,` or `/` just `explode(' /', $string);` maybe?

Comment: Did you want to match multiple spaces and slashes or just a signle space or slash? Maybe try `.` instead of `+`

Comment: For example, if I have the string "2 1/2", I want the array to be: [2,1,2]. I tried it on codepad and it does work... I am going to look more into my code to see what's wrong.